# Introductory Taylor Series Limit Proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Does there exist a function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ for which:

$$\lim_{\substack{x\in\mathbb R\\ x\to \infty}}f(x)\neq\lim_{\substack{n\in\mathbb{N}\\ n\to \infty}}f(n)?$$

I was thinking maybe a function that had a root at every natural number and oscillated towards infinity (kind of like $x\cdot \sin x$). It is okay if one limit DNE while the other does. All ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like 
$$\exp(x^2\sin^2(\pi x)).$$

The limit as $n\to\infty$ exists, the function is $1$ at the integers. And the function blows up for some $x$.

**Remark:** We used this instead of a simpler example because of the "Taylor series" in the title.

Comment: Why does the limit for n exist and not for x? What is the limit for n?

Comment: I wrote down the limit for $n$, it is $1$. For $\sin(\pi n)=0$ for all integers $n$. If we put $x=(n+1/2)\pi$, the $\sin^2$ is $1$, so we are looking at $\exp((n+1/2)^2)$, which goes to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't quite get why you made that substitution for x. Sorry, I am new to these kinds of conditional limit proofs...

Comment: Because at those places I knew that $\sin^2 x=1$, so the expression simplifies. I gave the wrong simplification in the comment, it is $\exp((n+1/2)^2\pi^2)$. Blows up a little faster! Could have used many other values of $x$, such as $2n\pi +\pi/6$. There the $\sin^2$ is $1/4$, and we get blowup.

Answer (score 2):

You could let
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
17 & x\not\in\mathbb Q \\
0 & x\in \mathbb Q
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\in\mathbb R,x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ DNE while $\displaystyle\lim_{x\in\mathbb N,x\rightarrow\infty}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not such a function.

If the limit exists for $x \rightarrow +\infty$, it needs to exist for all sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which tend to $+\infty$, in particular the natural numbers. If you write down $\lim$ on both sides, you assume that both limits exist.

However, if the function does not have a limit at $\infty$ because there are multiple limit points, it's possible that one subset of sequences converges towards one limit point, and another subset converges to a different limit point.